# docker command attach running slow

Tags: node.js, docker

i have docker container that adds 3 volumes and links to one other docker container. this linked container links to another one.

the container contains a nodejs server that is listening on one port.

the time for starting up the container is very short.

if i try to attach to that container it tooks sometimes 3 minutes until the attach-command runs.

could anyone give me a reason why the attach command tooks so long to start?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs 
RUN apt-get -y install npm
RUN npm install forever -g
RUN npm install n -g
RUN n 0.11.11
RUN npm install gulp -g
RUN mkdir -p data/dmcms-static-ng
RUN mkdir -p data/site-ng
RUN mkdir -p data/static-ng
ADD app-run.sh /app-run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh
```

Comment: post your attach and run, build commands. If necessary, app-run.sh code